# Convert string to dictionary to dataframe

Tags: python, json, string

I have data in string format as follows:

```
data = '{"ResponseStatus":404,"TieredFill":false} \n{"ResponseStatus":404,"TieredFill":false}\n'
```

when I try to dump this data to JSON, it gets converted into an empty file.
I am beginner in Python, so thinking to solve this, I need to convert string into dictionary and then into dataframe.

Any input on this or if there's another way to convert string to json would be helpful.

Comment: Where did you get the '\n' characters from ? is it a part of the data you get from somewhere ?

Comment: yes, it's the file I got to work on. It's like b'{"ResponseStatus":404,"TieredFill":false} \n{"ResponseStatus":404,"TieredFill":false}\n'

Comment: so when you open the file from a say text editor you visualize as `b'{"ResponseStatus":404,"TieredFill":false} \n{"ResponseStatus":404,"TieredFill":false}\n` ?

or is it looking like that after you load it via Python ?

Comment: Its looking like that when I load in Python. It's a log.gz file

Comment: Try the following and see if the data starts looking different `import gzip
f = gzip.open('xxxx.gz', 'rb')
data = f.read()`

Comment: trying mentioned using gzip only. @SupunDeSilva.

Answer (score 3):

Use `str.strip` and `split`:

```
[json.loads(j) for j in data.strip().split("\n")]
```

Output:

```
[{'ResponseStatus': 404, 'TieredFill': False},
 {'ResponseStatus': 404, 'TieredFill': False}]
```